# HTTP: set cookie for two subdomains exclusively

Tags: http, cookies, setcookie

Is it possible to set cookies for a specific list of subdomains?

Example: *a.example.com*, *b.example.com*, *c.example.com*, ...

I would like to set the same cookies for subdomains *a* and *b*, but **not** *c* and any other. So I can't use *example.com* as I don't want all subdomains to be included.

Can cookie domain be separated (e.g. comma)? Or can you have multiple Set-Cookie headers for the two specific subdomains above?

Thanks.